# how to select specific range from byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I can't find any direct function (*like mybytearray.copy(offset, count)*) that select range of bytes from byte array. So, do I have to loop through to copy required bytes?

Comment: Wait, wait. Do you want to specifically *select* a range from byte array, or *copy* a range from byte array to another array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) or [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

Dependent on what you exactly need, you might want to use LINQ. The syntax is self explaining :)

```
var newArr = currentArray.Skip(4).Take(300).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Chris_web what do you mean with "doesn't work"? If it doesn't compile, you should add using System.Linq; first :). Which .NET version do u use?

Comment: :) here my requirement is, from a 1024byte array, I have to copy 300bytes starting from 5th byte.

Comment: I believe this should be accepted answer! It doesn't need to create a new array and works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

You can use Buffer.blockcopy. link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx).